# How to DNS emails to vhosted domain to separate server than website

Tags: domain-name-system, postfix, mx-record, email-server

I apologize if this is a duplicate, but I'm not sure of the correct phrases to search to ensure this hasn't been solved yet.

I have 2 servers, with PTR records of `domain.com` and `mail.domain.com`.  The first server, does mass virtual hsoting of small website and applications, and the second server is intended to be a mailserver for those virtually hosted domains.

I have successfully used iredmail to get email running for the primary domain, using the SMTP server of `mail.domain.com`.  However, I can't seem to figure out how I need to setup my DNS settings for say `user@client.com`, such that `client.com` DNS resolves to server `domain.com`, but emails to `client.com` resolve to the server `mail.domain.com`.

I've tried setting mx records for `client.com` as using `mail.domain.com` with a priority of `10`, but then we start getting errors with emails to/from `domain.com`.

I know we need to do some postfix settings to rewrite user accounts, but how do I set the DNS so that the account `user@client.com` can use either `mail.domain.com` or `mail.client.com` as the i/o mail server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on the ip address the names resolve to, moreso than the names.  You want the `client.com` MX record to point to the IP address of the mail server.  Take care not to confuse yourself by thinking an A record to the name `mail.client.com` is the same as an MX record to `client.com`; it might be simpler not to have a `mail.client.com` address at all: just set an MX record for `client.com`.

1. set an MX record for `mail.domain.com` pointing to the ip address of the server receiving mail
2. set a CNAME record for `mail.client.com` pointing to `mail.domain.com`
3. configure the mail server to relay mail for `client.com` and `domain.com`

Test

1. get familiar with postfix and ensure port 25 of your mail server will not accept mail to `user@client.com` from the localhost
2. get familiar with `dig` and ensure the highest priority MX record for `client.com` ultimately resolves to the mail server's ip address.  Repeat for `mail.client.com`.

Comment: thx. I've been going with the "simpler not to have `mail.client.com`, but I started to wonder if I needed an mx record for it even though it wouldn't actually serve mail.  I have done `1` already, and I *think* we've done step `3` also. Seems step 2 might be that missing DNS record I was looking for.  the mail server relay for those domain would be done via postfix correct?

Comment: `client.com` should have an MX record, but it is appropriate to have `mail.domain.com` be its MX.  The mail server at `mail.domain.com` will need to know how to handle email for `client.com`.